# Story about female telepaths looking for compatible male telepath

Tags: story-identification, telepathy

A man runs into some women who can read minds. After he gets to know two of them, they ask if he would take part in a gene experiment that would allow him to control his own genes. He does and then changes into various animals including a phoenix.

Comment: Can you give us any more details, such as what language it was in, how long it was, etc?

Comment: I'm remembering the book as well. I'm thinking it was an novel that came out in the 70's, but could be off. His genetic treatment has him cycling through all the possibilities in his DNA. The women start freaking out when he becomes a phoenix, but he does end up a telepath with golden skin.